# Schedule WorkManager worker from a notification action

Tags: android, android-workmanager

The android documentation shows how to schedule a *WorkManager Worker* programmatically like so:

```
val uploadWorkRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<UploadWorker>()
        .build()

WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(uploadWorkRequest)
```

But how are you supposed to schedule it once a user clicks a notification action?

For example, this is the code to start an *IntentService* when a user clicks on a notification action:

```
class ApiCallService : IntentService("ApiCallService") {
   // ...
}

val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context,
            NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)

val saveIntent = Intent(context, ApiCallService::class.java)
val savePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                0, saveIntent, 0)

notificationBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_done_white_24dp,
                context.getString(R.string.save),
                savePendingIntent)
```

But instead of an *IntentService* how are you supposed to enqueue a *WorkManager Worker* when user clicks on the same notification action?

Comment: You can also call `WorkManager` work from `IntentService`. Because notification action can't done without `PendingIntent`!

Comment: @nick-bapu That's what I thought as well. I was hoping there was any method to directly schedule the worker, that's why I asked this question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IntentService is deprecated starting with API level 30:

> "IntentService is subject to all the background execution limits
> imposed with Android 8.0 (API level 26). Consider using WorkManager or
> JobIntentService, which uses jobs instead of services when running on
> Android 8.0 or higher."
> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService

SOLUTION: Simply create a standard service, associate it with your PendingIntent and start the WorkManager within the service's  onStartCommand-Method.

Answer (score 2):

IntentService has been deprecated. Please check the other answer.

<s>For anyone wondering how I solved this, I created an extra IntentService for scheduling different workers.</s>

```
class WorkManagerService : IntentService("WorkManagerService") {
    override fun onHandleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        when (intent?.action) {
            ACTION_SCHEDULE_WORKER1 -> {
                scheduleWorker1(intent)
            },
            ACTION_SCHEDULE_WORKER2 -> {
                scheduleWorker2(intent)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun scheduleWorker1(intent: Intent) {
        // ...

        val worker1 = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<Worker1>()
                .setConstraints(networkConstraint)
                .setInputData(workData)
                .build()

        WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(worker1)
    }

    private fun scheduleWorker2(intent: Intent) {
        // ...
    }
}
```